# JSON.stringify losing properties - Logging and saving all javascript events

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to log and save all the events that happens in a user session.

In order to do that, I'm having an array

```
var events = []
```

Having a listener for every event..

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.addEventListener("abort", handleEvent);
    window.addEventListener("blur", handleEvent);
    [...]
}
```

and sending the events:

```
function sendEvents() {
    axios.post('/api/logger', JSON.stringify(events));
}
```

The problem is that every sendEvents() is sending an array of events, but each of them have only two properties:

```
[{"isTrusted":true,"date":"2019-02-19T14:59:42.474Z"},{"isTrusted":true,"date":"2019-02-19T14:59:42.485Z"}
```

But it should have a LOT more properties, for example:

```
*altKey: false
bubbles: true
button: 0
buttons: 0
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
clientX: 662
clientY: 273
composed: true
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
date: Tue Feb 19 2019 12:08:38 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina) {}
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
fromElement: null
isTrusted: true
layerX: 662
layerY: 273
metaKey: false
movementX: 0
movementY: 0
offsetX: 662
offsetY: 273
pageX: 662
pageY: 273
path: (7) [header.App-header, div.App, div#root, body, html, document, Window]
relatedTarget: null
returnValue: true
screenX: 662
screenY: 400
shiftKey: false
sourceCapabilities: InputDeviceCapabilities {firesTouchEvents: false}
srcElement: header.App-header
target: header.App-header
timeStamp: 1605.000000000473
toElement: header.App-header
type: "mouseover"
which: 1
x: 662
y: 273*
```

Even if I don't stringify the array, in the backend the object have only the same two attributes. (I'm using nodejs + mongodb)

**How can I save the entire event object with all its properties?**

Comment: What does `handleEvent` do?

Comment: `const handleEvent = e => {
    e.date = new Date();
    events.push(e);`

Comment: I mean, it just add the current date and push the object to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a couple reasons for this. Most likely is those properties are not enumerable which causes them to not be included in JSON. (Properties are defined as `enumerable` via [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).) See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description

I would recommend explicitly declaring which properties you want to POST, since you probably don't need all of them anyway:

```
axios.post('/api/logger', JSON.stringify(events.map(event=>{
  return {
    altKey: event.altKey,
    bubbles: event.bubbles,
    // etc...
  }
}));
```

Comment: Yes, he's actually lucky to have the date, I just tested and got only `{"isTrusted":true}`. He should also be wary about `TypeError: cyclic object value` errors too

Comment: Works perfectly. That was the problem, those properties are not enumarable so json.stringify ignores it. Thank you!